# When was block 210000 generated and who solved it?

Tags: blockchain, history, reward-schedule

When was block 210000, the first block to feature halved 25BTC reward, generated and who solved it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/block-index/322335/000000000000048b95347e83192f69cf0366076336c639f9b7228e9ba171342e), the block 210000 was solved on 2012-11-28 15:24:38 GMT, and was relayed by Slush's Pool. The pool's [Stats](http://mining.bitcoin.cz/stats/) page also claims to have solved that block. It has also been stated that the block was solved by pool's user by the nickname of laughingbear.

Comment: According to this comment https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=128200.msg1363999#msg1363999 the Slush pool user who found the block was luckybear

Comment: Photo: http://i.imgur.com/EIoAD.jpg

Comment: I see now that the user was laughingbear.

Comment: Lol I thought the photo was an actual picture of laughingbear...