# How many Halving Days will there be?

Tags: mining-reward, reward-schedule

The first Halving Day was November 28, 2012, when [block 210000 was generated](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/when-was-block-210000-generated-and-who-solved-it).

How many more Halving Days will there be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There will be 32 more if the precision doesn't increase. If Bitcoin lasts this long (very unlikely), precision probably will be increased.

Comment: Why should the precision be increased? Many would argue that instead, we will see micropayments move off the blockchain and possibly bitcoin alltogether...

Comment: @pyramids If the value becomes really immense, it may become convenient to increase the precision. And scalability might be significantly improved after many years, possibly allowing microtransactions.

Answer (score 1):

The block subsidy will be reduced 33 times, 32 of them halving the block reward, and the last ("33rd halving") reducing it from 1 satoshi per block to zero satoshis per block.

You can find a table [here (Google doc)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12tR_9WrY0Hj4AQLoJYj9EDBzfA38XIVLQSOOOVePNm0) that shows some metrics of the Bitcoin reward schedule including e.g. the number of halvings, their first blocks, and how much supply is left to be mined after each epoch.